# Select processlist of all users with limited privileges assigned to a user

Tags: mysql

I am trying to select the count of the full processlist and the count of the full processlist where command is not 'sleep' from a mysql server. It is for a database check query which is executed every 5 minutes from an external server.

This is working fine with root user, but I don't want to use the root user on the external server. So I have created a new user with limited privileges.

```sql
USE information_schema;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PROCESSLIST WHERE COMMAND NOT LIKE 'Sleep'
UNION ALL SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PROCESSLIST;
```

But now the new user is just getting the own processes, so the result is just 1 and 1, but it should be for example 10 and 60. How can I get this working without using the root user?

Comment: What privileges are assigned to this new user ? You might need to open few more privileges for this user.

Comment: Thank you, you are right. Now I gave the new user full previleges and it is working. Next step is to find out which previleges are necessary for information_schemas.processlist. And I also forgot to flush previleges, so the new previlges where not used by the server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The new user which you have created needs to have [`PROCESS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_process) privilege enabled, in order to be able to access the processlist of other threads (besides his own thread).

From [MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/processlist-table.html):

> Like the output from the SHOW PROCESSLIST statement, the PROCESSLIST
>   table shows information only about your own threads, unless you have
>   the PROCESS privilege, in which case you will see information about
>   other threads, too. As an anonymous user, you cannot see any rows at
>   all.

and from the definition of [`PROCESS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_process) privilege:

> Enables display of information about the threads executing within the
>   server (that is, information about the statements being executed by
>   sessions). The privilege enables use of SHOW PROCESSLIST or mysqladmin
>   processlist to see threads belonging to other accounts; you can always
>   see your own threads. The PROCESS privilege also enables use of SHOW
>   ENGINE.

So, all you need to do is just enable the `PROCESS` privilege for the new user. You would need `SELECT` privilege as well.

```
GRANT PROCESS, SELECT ON *.* TO 'new_user_name'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: You are right, the user needs only Process_priv = 'Y'. Thank you.

Comment: SELECT privileges seems not needed (at least on mysql8).  Flush privileges should not be needed.